# android custom view rewrite its text from another custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view

i have created a custom view that contain just three edit view and textview

and in my bottom sheet dialog fragment, i have used twice with different ids,

when first display its ok, but in second calling, show first view filled with second one
(even using in another fragment and pressing back button i see this too)
[first time that display ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFGg2.jpg)
[first time with duplicated value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW5Zl.jpg)

> custom compuond xml file : edit_text_view

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:viewBindingIgnore="false">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/TextInputLayout"
        style="@style/EditText.OutlinedBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:hint="@tools:sample/cities">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/EditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextViewMessage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:textColor="@color/design_default_color_error"
        android:textDirection="anyRtl"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:text="@tools:sample/lorem"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

> custom compound  java file

```
public class EditTextOutlinedBox extends LinearLayout {
    private EditTextUtils editTextUtils;
    private EditTextViewBinding mBinding;

    public EditTextOutlinedBox(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initializeViews(context, null);
    }

    public EditTextOutlinedBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initializeViews(context, attrs);
    }

    public void requestEditTextFocus() {
        mBinding.EditText.requestFocus();
    }

    public EditTextOutlinedBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        initializeViews(context, attrs);
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public EditTextOutlinedBox(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        initializeViews(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();
//        editText = mBinding.EditText;
    }

    public void setGravity(int gravity) {
        mBinding.EditText.setGravity(gravity);
    }

    private void initializeViews(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {

            editTextUtils = new EditTextUtils();
            mBinding = EditTextViewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this, true);

            if (attrs != null) {
                @SuppressLint("CustomViewStyleable") TypedArray attributes = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.ViewCustomFont);
                int[] set = {
                        android.R.attr.background, // idx 0
                        android.R.attr.text,        // idx 1
                        android.R.attr.hint,       // idx 2
                        android.R.attr.inputType        // idx 3
                };
                TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, set);

                try {
                    //region text and hint
                    CharSequence text = styledAttributes.getText((int) 1);
                    if (ValidationUtils.Companion.isNotEmpty(text)) {
                        text = text.toString();
                        setText(text);
                    }
                    CharSequence hint = styledAttributes.getText((int) 2);
                    if (ValidationUtils.Companion.isNotEmpty(hint)) {
                        hint = hint.toString();
                        setHint(hint);
                    }

                    //endregion

                    //region font
                    int font = attributes.getInteger(R.styleable.ViewCustomFont_fonts, 0);

                    if (font == Typeface.IRANIAN_SANS_NORMAL.getValue()) {
                        mBinding.EditText.setTypeface(new TypefaceProvider().getIranianSans(context));
                    } else if (font == Typeface.IRANIAN_SANS_BOLD.getValue()) {
                        mBinding.EditText.setTypeface(new TypefaceProvider().getIranianSansBold(context));
                    }
                    //endregion

                    //region inputType
                    int inputType = styledAttributes.getInt((int) 3, EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL);
                    if (inputType != EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL) {
                        mBinding.EditText.setInputType(inputType);
                    }
                    //endregion
                } finally {
                    attributes.recycle();
                    styledAttributes.recycle();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public EditText getEditTextView() {
        return mBinding.EditText;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return editTextUtils.getText(mBinding.EditText);
    }

    public void setText(CharSequence text) {
        mBinding.EditText.setText(text);
    }

    public void setInputTypeAsDigit() {
        editTextUtils.setInputTypeAsDigit(mBinding.EditText);
        mBinding.EditText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,"));
        addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcherUtils().separateThousands(getContext(), mBinding.EditText, ",", "."));
    }

    public void addTextChangedListener(TextWatcher watcher) {
        editTextUtils.addTextChangedListener(mBinding.EditText, watcher);
    }

    public void setInputTypeAsPassword() {
        editTextUtils.setInputTypeAsPassword(mBinding.EditText);
    }

    public void setInputTypeAsNumberPassword() {
        editTextUtils.setInputTypeAsNumberPassword(mBinding.EditText);
    }

    public void setInputType(int inputType) {
        editTextUtils.setInputType(mBinding.EditText, inputType);
    }

    public CharSequence getHint() {
        return mBinding.TextInputLayout.getHint();
    }

    public void setHint(CharSequence hint) {
        mBinding.TextInputLayout.setHint(hint);
    }

    public void setMaxLength(int maxLength) {
        editTextUtils.setMaxLength(mBinding.EditText, maxLength);
    }

    public void setMaxLines(int maxLines) {
        editTextUtils.setMaxLines(mBinding.EditText, maxLines);
    }

    public void setError(String errorMessage) {
        editTextUtils.setError(mBinding.EditText, errorMessage);
        requestEditTextFocus();
    }

    public CharSequence getError() {
        return editTextUtils.getError(mBinding.EditText);
    }

    public boolean hasError() {
        return editTextUtils.hasError(mBinding.EditText);
    }

    public void setAsRequired() {
        editTextUtils.setAsRequired(getContext(), mBinding.EditText);
    }
    }
```

Comment: its two day and i check view binding , using merge , getting data ,from attrs but nothing helpd

Comment: It's not the view binding, or anything. It's the fact that you're ending up with two `EditText`s in that hierarchy with the same ID, and their text is being automatically saved and restored internally, which is just the default behavior. Same thing would happen with two platform `SearchView`s in place of your `EditTextOutlinedBox`s. You need to handle the save/restore yourself, either inside your custom `View`, or in the `Fragment`.

Comment: thank you for your response,
how can i handle save/restore ?

Comment: @MikeM, i appreciate your help, the problem solved
,now in method ```onSaveInstanceState``` im saving data and then in ```onRestoreInstanceState``` retrieve data